# Questions containing "or"

Tags: word-order, grammaticality

> Do you prefer to stay home, or do you want to come with us?
>   Should I prepare dinner, or are we going to go to the restaurant?

Are the questions correctly written?
Is there a preferred way to write such questions?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'm not sure what exactly the question is, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your approach to writing these two-in-one questions is correct.  You write the first question, add a comma and "or" and then ask the second one with a question mark at the end.  Multiple options can be separated with commas.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's written correctly. I'm not sure what you think could be incorrect, though. If you're worried about the usage of the comma before "or", your usage is correct.

Comment: I added another example to the question. What I am trying to understand is how to write a question that is made of two questions separated from _or_.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is combining two questions or two independent clauses with a coordinating conjunction, which conjoins two or syntactically identical units. The comma before the conjunction (when dealing with two clauses) is stylistic and optional, though I'd personally recommend it.

Your examples look perfect.